# Restrict access to folder inside public_html

Tags: php, wordpress, .htaccess

I am currently making a WordPress user system, that is supposed to feature private files, that can be uploaded to each user. In order to achieve this, I am using a filter that places the files in question in a subfolder to uploads named secretfiles. The filter won't allow me to place the files outside the public_html, so I have to do it this way.

Now I am planning to exclude all access to the this 'secretfiles' folder using .htacces, and write a downloadscript that checks whether a user is allowed to download requested files, before sending them to him.

Would this be a safe way to make the files truly private, even though they are placed inside the public_html folder. And what would my .htaccess code be?

Thanks!

Comment: What have you tried? Where's the code you're using that demonstrates the problem? Why wouldn't the filter allow you to place the files outside public_html? What is this filter? What does it do? Did you [read the Apache httpd manual](https://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.4/howto/access.html) to learn how to restrict access? Did you read [how to ask a question](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) in the StackOverflow help center to get some guidelines about how to ask before asking?

Comment: This certainly is possible. It is not great, but maybe all you can do according to your own words. Whether it is "safe" is another question, since there are endless of aspects to consider we do not know about. Generally using a simple web hoster (it sounds as if you do) can _never_ be considered safe, since you have absolutely no control over your files in that situation.

Comment: About the exact rules you have to configure: please start by reading the excellent documentation offered for the modules of the apache http server. You will find good explanations and a wealth of great examples.

Answer (score 0):

You can deny all access from directly accessing the files in a directory using an .htaccess file (see below example). Users can still access this files if they have been enclosed in a download script as suggested. Note, that the download script should not be a redirection. It should send the file itself.

```
Deny from all
```

Comment: Wouldn't it make much more sense to block access to the folder instead of specific file name extensions? What about the folder index for example? And other file name extensions? Upper case for example?

Comment: You changed the code, you should also change your description to match it. This are confusing the way they are now...